# ActorSystem singleton injection

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, singleton, akka, akka-actor

In my project, I have to use actors and schedulers. All my need can be accomplished by using one actor system only. But I need the schedulers and actors in more than one class. So my question, if I should inject the actor system in each class like below, will it create only one actor System or more than one? I don't want to create more than one actor system since it is not a recommended practice.

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem

@Singleton
class someClass @Inject()(actorSystem: ActorSystem){....} // abstract class ActorSystem extends ActorRefFactory

@Singleton
class anotherClass @Inject()(actorSystem: ActorSystem){....}
```

Or I should create another object and declare an actor system within it and use it everywhere like this:

```
import akka.actor._

object actorSystemObject {
    val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem()
}
```

Which method will be better and standard?

Comment: Certainly better to avoid global objects, use some form of dependency injection instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using guice, try [providing](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ProvidesMethods#provides-methods) a [singleton](https://github.com/google/guice/blob/ece6a9fce38df306991a4568764ba8fb86ced022/core/src/com/google/inject/Singleton.java#L26) like so

```
@Provides
@Singleton
def getActorSystem: ActorSystem = ActorSystem()
```

for example

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import com.google.inject.{AbstractModule, Guice, Inject, Injector, Provides, Singleton}
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._

class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Provides
  @Singleton
  def getActorSystem: ActorSystem = ActorSystem()
}

@Singleton
class SomeClass @Inject()(actorSystem: ActorSystem) {
  println(actorSystem.hashCode())
}

@Singleton
class SomeOtherClass @Inject()(actorSystem: ActorSystem) {
  println(actorSystem.hashCode())
}

object Hello extends App {
  val injector: Injector = Guice.createInjector(List(new MyModule).asJava)
  injector.getInstance(classOf[SomeClass])
  injector.getInstance(classOf[SomeOtherClass])
}
```

which outputs something like

```
1731656333
1731656333
```

where we see the same `ActorSystem` is injected as evident by the same `hashCode`.

Say we remove `@Singleton` provider like so

```
@Provides
def getActorSystem: ActorSystem = ActorSystem()
```

then `hashCode`s differ, for example,

```
2050462663
1117871068
```